# Mysql Partition pruning not working on my subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, partition, pruning

```
explain 
SELECT
    ip_src,
    (SELECT country FROM ip_location WHERE ip_start between (134744072-500000) and (134744072) and ip_end > 134744072) country_src,
    ip_dst
FROM
    event e
WHERE 
    long_date BETWEEN '2016-03-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-25 23:59:59'
LIMIT 1
```

---

### [partition pruning working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYVyl.png)

```
explain
SELECT
    ip_src,
    (SELECT country FROM ip_location WHERE ip_start between (ip_src-500000) and (ip_src) and ip_end > ip_src) country_src,
    ip_dst
FROM
    event e
WHERE 
    long_date BETWEEN '2016-03-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-25 23:59:59'
LIMIT 1
```

[partition pruning not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rod6j.png)

I have 2 query, 
ip_src value is 134744072.

My Ip_location table is partitioned by range on ip_start column.
When I run first query, its done with partition pruning, but in second query its access all partition.

Anyone please give me clue, i have looking around n dont know yet whats going on, thankyou before :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimizer that decides on the execution plan, including which partitions it doesn't need, runs before the actual data is read from the table.

Your first query restricts your subquery to a specific range for `ip_start` between the constant values `134744072-500000` and `134744072`, so it is clear which partition the data is in. (Btw.: you have to make sure that subquery returns max. one row, otherwise it will result in an error).

For your second query, the optimizer cannot know the required range before it starts. It will depend on the data it finds when it reads the `event` table.  That is why the `select_type` for this query is a `dependent subquery`, while for the first query, it's a `subquery` (so a fixed resultset independent of the `event` table). So the optimizer cannot exclude a partition yet, so it will list them all. When the query is executed, it will read the first row, now knows that the value for `ip_src` is `134744072`, and therefore the `ip_start`-range and the partition the data is in, and so MySQL will now look it up in the correct partition.

Both queries will actually only read from that one partition, but for the the first one, MySQL knows that before it starts, for the second one, it doesn't.

And finally a warning: it looks like you are trying to use partitions to speed up your query. This is not what partitions are used for! Indexes are used for that. For `limit 1`, it will not make a difference, but if you query more rows, each partition will act like an independent table (which it basically is), so instead of looking up data in 1 index (of a larger table, but the size basically does not matter when you have an index), MySQL has to look up data in 30, 40 different partitions (=tables), all having their own indexes, files and structures. This will usually be slower (and almost never faster) than not using partitions. 600k rows might already be enough to see at least a small effect of that, so do a test without partitioning.

Comment: Ya right, I think partition make query faster because its not read the whole table, CMIIW. I also implement index on my partition table.

thank you for the explanation about optimizer. The second query seems read all the partition. I will try using non partition table with index on ip_start and ip_end, I report it later :)

Comment: @SyanduIrdoni To your CMIIW: the index is there to prevent you from reading the whole table. Best case: Partitioning will increase the overhead a little bit until you can read your table (deciding which partition the data is in, managing several tables/indexes). Worst case: you query/order for anything without knowing `ip_start`, e.g. `select * from ip_location where country = 'us'`. Even with an index on `country`, it requires access to (the indexes of) all partitions. But I'm looking forward if you actually see a difference in your test - your query is the "best case" type, so it's small.